# Listen for user input all the time

Tags: java

I started with JAVA yesterday and I´m about to build a simple snake game in the console to get started without any tutorials. I´m familiar with JS though.

The challenge I´m facing is the user input. I´m using the class `Scanner`, however this requires to press enter to get the previously pressed keys.

Is it possible to listen to the user input and return the pressed key as soon as a key is pressed(basically skipping the enter) with the Scanner' class? 
Alternatives?

Here´s my code(feel free to give me advices, as I said above, I started yesterday):

```
package Snake;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake player = new Snake();
        Field field = new Field();
        field.drawField(player.positionX, player.positionY);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean x = false;

        do {
            switch(scanner.nextLine().charAt(0)) {
            case 'a': 
                field.drawField(player.positionX-=1, player.positionY);
                break;
            case 'b':
                System.out.println("You said b");
                break;
            case 'x':
            System.out.println("Closed by pressing x");
            x = true;
            break;
        }
    } while(!x);
}
}
```

Comment: If you're writing a game, you should use a JFrame and a KeyListener instead of Scanner (unless you use a game library of course).

Comment: or you can throw your test cases in a file and append `< file.txt` to your program.

Comment: You need to escape the `Enter` key pressed after entering the key. Refer this question [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: scanner is not for real time input